# Sharing logic across different platforms

Tags: cross-platform

We have a business logic that works with the file systems on OS that we want to implement on both Linux and Windows platforms. The language we have selected is Python for Linux and C# for Windows. GUI is not a priority for now. We were looking for ways to abstract the business logic in a way that we dont have to repeat the business logic (ofcourse I understand since it is related to file system, some code will differ from platform to platform).

Any ideas on how to implement it? Is C/C++ the only option. We dont want to use Java.

Thanks,
Pranz

Comment: Why not use Python for both Linux AND Windows?  That would make your business logic the same on both platforms.

Comment: Python is ok, c# is ok, java is not ok? And are all the programmers required to wear lederhosen? This seems really silly and arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

yea, pick a common language for the logic first. Punting down in to C/C++ pretty much eliminates any of the real values to development that the Python and C# languages provide. Done write, MOST of your logic will be "Business Logic" with the rest glue to external services (i.e. databases, etc.).

So, you should pick a portable environment from the get go. Dropping down to C/C++ and linking it in is a viable alternative, but most likely not worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an option you'll probably want to look into.

Quote from the site for easy explanation:

> Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. Sponsored by Novell, Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for development of Linux applications.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Mono or Python.

Mono allows you to run C# .NET code on both platforms. Python can be executed on both platforms already.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has cross-platform libraries for all sorts of things, including UI and file system.  It does, however, use C++.